# System.File.Info and string[]

Tags: c#, asp.net, directory

I am wondering how I can get all the files with File Info and not in a string because I need to get the informations from the creationTime etc ...

This is the code I use

```
string[] fiArr = Directory.GetFiles( "C://inetpub//wwwroot//Files//" + param[i], "*",
                                     SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`GetFiles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143327.aspx) method on the `DirectoryInfo` class.

```
string path = Path.Combine("C:/inetpub/wwwroot/Files/", param[i]);
DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(path);
FileInfo[] fileInfos = directoryInfo.GetFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

Also you should use [`Path.Combine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt.aspx) rather than string concatenation to combine paths.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a DirectoryInfo first and use it tio get a list of FileInfo's

The basic pattern (there are a number of overloads):

```
var folder = new DirectoryInfo(".");
var infos = folder.GetFiles();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:/Path");
var infoFiles = dirInfo.GetFiles();
```